# navigator.credentials on safari

Tags: html, safari

I'm trying to create an application that allows users to save their passwords and login again with that account at a later time. `navigator.credentials` was made for this, but it doesn't seem to work in safari, although it looks supported here: [https://developer.mozilla.org/](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/credentials)

When I call something like `navigator.credentials.get({ password: true, mediation: 'required' })` in safari, I get `NotSupportedError: Only PublicKeyCredential is supported.`

Is this feature incorrectly marked as supported in safari? Google searching this problem has a been nightmare.

Context:

- nextjs / react
- Safari Version 14.1.1

Answer (score 0):

PasswordCredential seems not supported in Safari and Firefox:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PasswordCredential

Not sure the alternative here, also looking for one, same problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30701308)

Comment: @Sercan, it does answer the following question from OP:

"Is this feature incorrectly marked as supported in safari?"

The answer, this feature is not supported by Safari for PasswrodCredentials, which is what the OP is after.  The feature is only supported by Safari for Public Key.

Comment: You are giving an answer that you are not sure of and your answer consists only of a link. That's why I shared support information during the review.

Comment: Link is to substantiate.  OP mentioned he googled and couldn't find an authoritative answer, so I gave them one.  I am not an authority on this but have been searching same.

Comment: The support messages shared during the review are only to inform the respondent and help him/her better organize his/her answer. It was automatically redirected to my posts during the review, probably because another user flagged your answer.